# Searchmonkey crashes repeatedly with one type of search in Ubuntu 20.04 searching for a word in data files

Tags: 20.04, searchmonkey

I have tried the following search many times, and each time, searchmonkey crashes.

I ran it from the command line, and before loading, it came up with:-

```
Gtk-Message: 18:03:31.919: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

After a while, searchmonkey, crashed with the following message:-

```
Killed
```

From memory, this is possibly the only time that searchmonkey has crashed - but everytime I run the search, it crashes.

The search is to look on local - or the network drives for any files containing a particular word - I have even tried making it more sophisticated, by adding more than one word, to help narrow down the search/ speed it up...
Any clues as to what is awry/ how to overcome this issue?
Many thanks for your help....